# Merging two Windows form UIs into single UI

Tags: windows-forms-designer

I have two Windows form applications using C#. One is for acquiring data from a spectrometer. This application includes lots of references and assembly files require to interface Ocean Optics spectrometer with Visual Studio 2012

Another application which send this data to Mathematica tool for signal processing and retrieve back result and display it on UI of second application.

I want to integrate these two apps' UIs into one UI, so that from the single UI front end, I will be able to acquire and send data to Mathematica and retrieve back the result and display it on the UI.

Comment: In theory, you can create a new application, which embeds the windows of these two apps into panels of its form.  *But*.  There are many implications and the results will depend greatly on how these two apps are designed and implemented.  Do you have the source of these two apps?

Comment: I have downloaded these two apps' code from internet and edited according to my requirement. But when  I tried to embed one into another, it is not working. The UI of only one app is being showed. The other app's controls are disappeared. I have only copy pasted the code in Form1.cs.